# Как изменить value при клике по кнопке чистым JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть следующая разметка. Как на чистом js написать чтобы при клике на кнопку плюс - увеличить value на 1, при клике на кнопку минус - уменьшить на 1. При этом значение value не должно быть меньше 1. Буду благодарен за помощь!

```
<button class="js-plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
<input id="number-diet" class="js-number" type="number" name="number" value="1">
<button class="js-minus-btn" type="button">-</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```js
function countFunc(count) {
  var btnPlus = count.querySelector('.js-plus-btn');
  var btnMinus = count.querySelector('.js-minus-btn');
  var field = count.querySelector('.js-number');
  var fieldValue = parseFloat(field.value, 10);

  btnMinus.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (fieldValue > 1) {
      fieldValue--;
      field.value = fieldValue;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  });
  btnPlus.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fieldValue++;
    field.value = fieldValue;
  });

}
var counts = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
counts.forEach(countFunc);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="js-plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
  <input id="number-diet" class="js-number" type="number" name="number" value="1" min="1">
  <button class="js-minus-btn" type="button">-</button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="js-plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
  <input id="number-diet" class="js-number" type="number" name="number" value="1" min="1">
  <button class="js-minus-btn" type="button">-</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Коряво написал, но работает. Надеюсь, другие поправят, если что.

```js
let pole = document.getElementById("number-diet");

let plus = document.getElementsByClassName("js-plus-btn")[0];

let minus = document.getElementsByClassName("js-minus-btn")[0];

plus.addEventListener("click", function(){pole.value = parseInt(pole.value) + 1;});

minus.addEventListener("click", function(){if(parseInt(pole.value) > 1)pole.value = parseInt(pole.value) -+ 1;});
```

```html
<button class="js-plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
<input id="number-diet" class="js-number" type="number" name="number" value="1" disabled >
<button class="js-minus-btn" type="button">-</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```js
var plus = document.getElementsByClassName('js-plus-btn')[0];
var minus = document.getElementsByClassName('js-minus-btn')[0];
var field = document.getElementById('number-diet');

plus.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  field.value = Calc(1); 
});
minus.addEventListener('click', function(){
  field.value = Calc(-1);  
});

function Calc(oper) {
  let result = parseInt(field.value) + oper ; 
  return (result < 1) ? 1 : result;
}
```

```html
<button class="js-plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
<input id="number-diet" class="js-number" type="number" name="number" value="1">
<button class="js-minus-btn" type="button">-</button>
```